# ssh login using public keys for users that do not (yet) exist

Tags: ssh

In Linux (e.g., Ubuntu 18.04), how can I configure `sshd` to allow logins using public keys for OS users that do not yet exist?

For example:

1. On server: /etc/ssh/sshd_config has `AuthorizedKeysFile: /etc/ssh/keys/%u`
2. `sudo mkdir -p /etc/ssh/keys`
3. `sudo tee /etc/ssh/keys/foo <<< "$(cat id_rsa.pub)"`
4. `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
5. On client: ssh foo@server

In this scenario, the server does NOT have a `foo` account in `/etc/passwd`, but I'd like to create one automatically and then use `pam_mkhomedir` to create its home directory -- all because the user can successfully authenticate using a public key.

My attempt:

1. `/etc/pam.d/sshd` comment out `@include common-auth` (makes no difference since public keys reportedly bypass this anyway)
2. `/etc/pam.d/sshd` comment out `@include common-account` (no difference)
3. `/etc/pam.d/sshd` add, under #2, `account required  pam_permit.so` (no difference)
4. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config LogLevel: DEBUG3` shows

```
debug1: userauth-request for user foo 
Invalid user foo from 192.168.0.8 port 62083
debug1: PAM: initializing for "foo"
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable for RSA SHA256:kdI+ALYK88R6zAcoPAIyXctjCLgEkGodgieusIOay0c [preauth]
debug2: userauth_pubkey: disabled because of invalid user [preauth]
```

Comment: The user is authenticating with their _private_ key. The server requires the public key to verify that. Since you have the public key, why not create the user at that time?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe Presumably because there is not a 1:1 mapping between public keys and users.

Comment: @JonBentley OK. I wouldn't do it that way (because of revocation, mostly), but fair enough.

Comment: You're both right. The rationale is that we need to ssh into these hosts using Active Directory (AD) to provide their /etc/group and /etc/passwd entries. If I add user `bar` to AD, the Linux host doesn't have an /etc/passwd entry yet--i.e., the `1:1` mapping (public key to passwd entry) does not exist yet. We need a `plugin for PAM` like `t3ddftw` mentioned in his answer. Also, we can centralize ssh revocations through AD using `Allow log on locally` with the Linux hosts in an Organizational Unit (OU). The keypair is pre-auth (i.e., pre-PAM), but, for us, SSSD to AD is the "glue".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't do this without writing your own plugin for PAM.

Depending on your business needs, it may actually make more sense to hook the box to an LDAP backend for the user database.

To get a little more specific, `sshd` is going to look to PAM to authenticate the user. If the user database doesn't have a record, the user will be set to `unknown`, which is going to create a nightmare of an experience for the user. Further, there is no PAM module that I'm familiar with that will take the username supplied by `sshd` and create a record of it in `passwd`.

Answer (score 4):

FreeIPA together with SSSD may be the right answer to your question: keep the user database in one place (FreeIPA) and let the workstation to consult it (SSSD) for user information and create the home directories for them on the fly (pam_mkhomedir). FreeIPA even lets you to keep ssh public keys in database, you don't have to enroll them to each and every workstation.

Comment: Does FreeIPA/SSSD support creating a 'composite' directory where the majority of attributes would be for example retrieved from AD while SSH keys could be stored in a different directory for the same user?  I'm thinking of the `meta` backend for OpenLDAP as an example.

Comment: I have no idea. I know there are some provisions to bridge FreeIPA and AD but I cannot say if they can do what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, FreeIPA allows you to store overrides for AD users in itself. Overrides include POSIX attributes, SSH public keys, certificates, etc. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/windows_integration_guide/index for more details.